# Error : OSError: libmediainfo.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I am getting this error while I am trying to run this and send sending an audio file from the system.

```
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libmediainfo.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

from __future__ import print_function
import time
import deepaffects
from deepaffects.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

# Configure API key authorization: UserSecurity
deepaffects.configuration.api_key['apikey'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
# create an instance of the API class
api_instance = deepaffects.DenoiseApi()
body = deepaffects.Audio.from_file('final_test1.wav') # Audio | Audio object that needs to be denoised.**Error in this line** 
webhook = 'https://webhook.site/9da66e31-c5cc-4474-8d72-7320eaa7c406' # str | The webhook 
url where result from async resource is posted
#request_id = 'request_id_example' # str | Unique identifier for the request (optional)

try:
    # Denoise an audio file
    api_response = api_instance.async_denoise_audio(body, webhook)
    print(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling DenoiseApi->async_denoise_audio: %s\n" % e)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should properly install libmediainfo-dev,

If you are using Ubuntu or debian run:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y libmediainfo-dev
```

If you're using redhat, centos or fedora run:

```
yum install libmediainfo
```